# Stuck with eloquent query and subquery

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to display in a table the name of the user as well as the number of photos posted during the current week.
Example : User1 has posted 10 photos, User2 has posted 20 photos...

So I need a count, but I'm not sure how.

Picture model :

```php
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

User model :

```php
public function pictures()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Picture');
}
```

Query in the controller :

```php
$users = User::whereHas('pictures', 
      fn($q) => $q->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->toDateTimeString()))
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

In the view:

```php
{{ $user->photos->count() }}
```

Except that it counts all the photos of the user and not just the photos for the past week. How can I only count the recent photos?

Comment: Could you please post the `User` and `Picture` models?

Comment: I edit the post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new relationship is a valid way to solve your problem, but here's another option.

You can use the `withCount()` method. By passing an array, you can use a closure to limit the results of the count to match the constraint on the relation:

```php
$users = User::whereHas(
        'pictures',
        fn($q) => $q->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subWeek())
    )
    ->withCount([
        'pictures' => fn ($q) => $q->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subWeek()
    ])
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Now in your view, you can use `$user->pictures_count`.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you! I validated & voteup

Answer (score 1):

I do this :

In the User model :

```
public function current_week_pictures()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Picture')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()]);
}
```

Query in the controller :

```
$users = User::whereHas('current_week_pictures')
            ->with('current_week_pictures')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();
```

In the view, to count :

```
{{ $user->pictures->count() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you get users which post a photo since last 7 days.

```
$users = User::whereHas('pictures', 
          fn($q) => $q->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->toDateTimeString()))
         ->limit(10)
         ->get();
```

Then here you try to count the number of photo a user have

```
$user->photos->count()
```

But you count only **photos of users which post last 7 days**, not the photos posted last 7 days.

Try do continue this Eloquent to count only photos which are posted last 7 days

Comment: That's exactly it, I count all the pictures and not those of the last 7 days

Comment: I need to do a query on $users or subquery in the current query ?

Comment: try something like $user->photos->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->toDateTimeString() )

Comment: I added an answer with my solution, is it feasible or there is better / cleaner?

Comment: What is the point of this answer? You're just reposting the question.

Comment: @miken32 ? I posted the solution I used, which works, it's solved